# Force Mobile Users to App, But Use Webview In App

Tags: ios, webview, media-queries

I am working on a web project, in which I would like to force users who open the site on a mobile browser to be directed to a landing page promoting them to download the app.

Problem is, I would like to use a mobile version of the site in a WebView in the app.

How can I distinguish between mobile browsers, and a WebView inside an app?

Comment: *Force* a user who wants to view your website to download an "app" that let's them view your website? No thanks. I like chrome. This probably won't be a happy UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a private url or a GET parameter when loading from the app.

For example if your website is www.example.com: You can if someone goes to that address you can show a certain webpage, if they go to it with a mobile device they go to another page. To do that you do the following in apache:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (OneMobileUserAgent|AnotherMobileUserAgent|...)
RewriteRule (.*) mobile/$1
```

which would move mobile requests from `http://example/index.html` to `http://example/mobile/index.html`

for the webView of the app all you do is go to a different address like: webView.example.com or www.example.com/webview

Comment: could you explain this a bit further, or possibly link me to some reference material? I'm not quite sure how to implement this :)